# Add database username and password along with server usrnm and pwd

Tags: php, html, database

I have this code that inserts user data into a database.

```
mysql_connect("server address","username","password");
mysql_select_db("login");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO login(name,username,password,email)VALUES('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[username]','$_POST[pw]','$_POST[email]')") or die("cannot execute the query");
```

I have an issue here. There is a username and password to enter into my server and there is also another username and password to use my database.

Where should I mention both username's and password's?

Comment: Not the answer to your question but please look into sanitizing your strings and also look into mysqli prepared statements! You should never directly input form data into a database incase of sql injection

Comment: @AndyHolmes I couldn't agree more. I am astonished to see the amount of times these questions are being asked and contain these kind of errors. And I don't want to know how many times these questions are not asked and the security flaws slip under the carpet. I wonder how secure are our accounts on the web...

Comment: Just to add on to what has been said by Andy and Mosty, look into mysqli_ or more preferable choice is PDO.

Haha @MostyMostacho, good question XD

Comment: @MostyMostacho I know, it's concerning. I just don't get why people aren't seeing the newer practices online for security etc and following suite. Crazy isn't it

Answer (score 2):

The `mysql_connect()` has absolutely nothing to do with server logins, and only has to do with MySQL login.

That being said, you have a number of issues:

1. You are using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. You should use `mysqli` extension of `PDO` instead.
2. You are horribly vulnerable to SQL injection attackes.  NEVER, EVER, EVER use directly input data from the user (like `$POST`, `$_GET`, etc.) without first sanitizing/validating it.
3. You really should get in the habit of checking the response for each function and handling errors appropriately.  For example, you should never even get to `mysql_query()` line of code if you `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` calls are not successful.

Comment: I am using the stripslashes and striptags functions in the user registration page itself. So, I guess its OK right?

Comment: @GreatKai You need to sanitize input data each and every time you are working with it.  Just because you sanitized data when inserting it into the database doesn't mean reading from the DB with unsanitized data is safe.